# Retrieving File name for bash/shell programing

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to access two files in my shell script. The only issue is , I am not sure what the file name is going to be as it is system generated.A part of the file name is always constant , but the rest of it is system generated , hence may vary. I am not sure how to access these files?

**Sample File Names**

*Type 1*

`MyFile1.yyyy-mm-dd_xx:yy:zz.log`

In this case , I know MyFile1 portion is a constant for all the files, the other portion varies based on date and time. I can use `date +%Y-%m-%d` to get till `MyFile1.yyyy-mm-dd_` but I am not sure how to select the correct file. Please note each day will have just one file of the kind. In unix the below command gives me the correct file .

`unix> ls MyFile1.yyyy-mm-dd*`

*Type 2*

`MyFile2.yyyymmddxxyyxx.RandomText.SomeNumber.txt`

In this file , as you can see Myfile2 portion is common,I can user  `Date +%Y%m%d` to get till (current date) `MyFile2.yyyymmdd`, again not very clear how to go on from there .In unix the below command gives me the correct file .Also I need to have previous date in the dd column for File 2.

`unix> ls MyFile2.yyyymmdd*`

basically looking for the following line in my shell script

```
#!/bin/ksh
timeA=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
timeB=$(date +%Y%m)
sysD=$(date +%d)
sysD=$((sysD-1))
filename1=($Home/folder/MyFile1.$timeA*)
filename2=($Home/folder/MyFile2.$timeB$sysD*)
```

Just not sure how to get the RHS for these two files.

The result when running the above scripts is as below

```
Script.ksh[8]: syntax error at line 8 : `(' unexpected
```

Comment: @StevenPenny I am simplu looking for `file=MyFile1.yyyy-mm-dd_xx:yy:zz.log` in shell script. How to get the RHS is my issue. Let me know if you are looking for any further details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this

```sh
$ file=(MyFile1.yyyy-mm-dd*)

$ echo $file
MyFile1.yyyy-mm-dd_xx:yy:zz.log
```

It should be noted that you must declare variables in this manner

```
foo=123
```

NOT

```
foo = 123
```

Notice carefully, bad

```
filename1=$($HOME/folder/MyFile1.$timeA*)
```

good

```
filename1=($HOME/folder/MyFile1.$timeA*)
```

Comment: @misguided: @StevenPenny's approach should work. Sounds like you (still) have a space between the variable name and the `=` sign. Also note that what the assignment yields is actually an *array*; accessing it without index will give you the first element. Finally: If there is NO matching file, the array will still have 1 element: the unexpanded globbing pattern (the string with the `*` wildcard). Therefore, test the value with, e.g., `[[ -f $filename1 ]]` to detect this case.